# QEMU USB Passthrough Error: libusb_set_configuration: -99 [OTHER]

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, usb, passthrough

I'm trying to pass through a Spectrum Digital TMS320C6713 DSK to a Windows 2000 virtual machine, and when I connect it it appears in device manager, but whenever I try to actually use the device, it immediately detaches and I get this error:

```
libusb: error [op_set_configuration] failed, error -1 errno 32
2017-11-17T19:56:11.626111Z qemu-system-x86_64: libusb_set_configuration: -99 [OTHER]
libusb: error [op_set_configuration] failed, error -1 errno 32
2017-11-17T19:56:11.628796Z qemu-system-x86_64: libusb_set_configuration: -99 [OTHER]
```

I've tried it with both Windows 2000 and Windows XP, and both of them result in the same error. (Unfortunately the software needed to interface with the boards will only run on 2000 or XP.)

I'm using unRAID with QEMU 2.7.1 and libusb 0.1.12.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don’t you have a permission issue? Have you tried USB pass-through with a different device, such as a keyboard, a mouse or a thumb drive?

Comment: @user2233709 I've tried passing through other devices and they all work fine.